# Child Views that are translated, scaled or rotated disappear

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a `ViewGroup` and I'm adding child Views to it like this:

```
mViewGroup.addView(view, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

(the `WRAP_CONTENT` is important for the `onclicklistener` to work as expected).

So far so good, but later I move the child Views around dynamically by either overriding their `onDraw` methods or by overriding the ViewGroups:

```
protected boolean getChildStaticTransformation(View child, Transformation t)
```

The problem is that the Children disappear if they are moved outside their original region which seems to be calculated when they are first added. I tried calling `setClipChildren(false);` but it didn't work.

I could solve the problem by using `LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT` when adding the child views but in this case the `onClickListener` would react to any click on the whole `ViewGroup` and I want it to only react to clicks on the specific area where my transformed child View is located.

Maybe I could still use `LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT` if there is a way to define where the clickable region for the `View` should be.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should experiment with margins and paddings of your child views. Otherwise you could try to use a different ViewGroup layout like a FrameLayout where the postion of each view can be set by its margins.